# Xorg at 99% CPU when moving pointer in circles; pointer device shows up twice

Tags: xorg, mouse, cpu-usage

I've acquired a new ergonomic mouse ([this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001FWKA7A)) and it behaves strangely.

When I begin moving the mouse, Xorg's CPU usage skyrockets, resulting in occasionally choppy mouse movement.

Futher, it shows up twice in the `xinput` listing.

I am running Xubuntu on an IBM ThinkPad P50.

```
$ uname -
Linux ███████████ 4.8.0-52-generic #55~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 14:36:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Notice here that my ergonomic keyboard also shows up as a pointer — not sure if this is part of the issue (`PixArt Gaming Mouse` is the offender):

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                    id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Gaming Mouse                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                         id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt Gaming Mouse                           id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ KINESIS FREESTYLE KB800 KB800 Kinesis Freestyle       id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                     id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                  id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ KINESIS FREESTYLE KB800 KB800 Kinesis Freestyle       id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                  id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                        id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I am running Xorg (obviously):

```
$ aptitude show xorg
Package: xorg
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 1:7.7+13ubuntu3
```

My hardware:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
3e:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

And I am running the Nouveau Nvidia driver.

I have tried enabling/disabling the pointer devices using `xinput` as well as `modprobe drm_kms_helper poll=N` and `modprobe usbhid mousepoll=...` with various values.

**ETA:** I have tried switching to metacity for window management using `metacity --replace`, to no avail.

Comment: Try different window managers (maybe this is not Xorg specific).

I've got similar problem with multiple keyboards and everything works fine on fluxbox, but xfce is pain in the butt.

Comment: @DevilaN tried metacity, didn't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a dual GPU (intel/nvidia) [i think they call it bumblebee?]. It's a laptop and the problem may be related to when I close the lid, or use it for a long time on battery but I'm not sure.